# Trigger action according to diagnostics

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, diagnostic-aggregator, diagnostics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have nodes publishing diagnostic data and I have configured them correctly and I can visualize them in Rviz.

But now I would like to trigger some actions, for example ring a buzzer when one sensor fails.

Do I need to create my own diagnostic analyzer that will do what I need ? Or do I need to write a node that will subscrive to `/diagnostics_agg` or `/diagnostics_toplevel_state` ?

Thanks a lot ! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355153/trigger-action-according-to-diagnostics/) by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2020-06-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Diagnostics were really originally designed for human readable outputs. The diagnostics_aggregator really exists to clean up diagnostics and re-arrange them for human viewing - the aggregator uses Analyzers (there is a [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostics/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20Diagnostic%20Analyzer) on creating custom analyzers).

The messages are generally not ideal for machine processing (while there are warning levels, most of the information tends to be string-based) - but you could certainly do that. You would almost certainly have to write your own node which could subscribe to either of the aggregated or non-aggregated diagnostics topics.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2020-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1